# Plotting High Dimensional Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I have got a data of size 13558x100 and I am trying to plot it. For 2D, I could use:

```
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2))
```

How can I plot this big data? Can I just use surf to visualize the data or is there any other way?

Comment: How about [`imagesc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)? It avoids the perspective problems associated to `surf` or to any 3D graph

Comment: [`pcolor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) is another option, besides `imagesc` and `surf`.

Comment: @LuisMendo consider putting it as an answer

Comment: If you have 13558 points, each of which is 100 dimensional. There is no straightforward way to visualize that data in 100 dimensions. However, you can employ dimensionality reduction techniques like PCA and then visualize its first two or three principle components. If you want to visualize it as a matrix, then `imagesc` works.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar OP didn't specify if it's highly correlated, but I agree with your suggestion

Comment: Hi @ParagS.Chandakkar, thanks for the suggestion. I would better perform PCA and analyze some dimensions. :)

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned `imagesc` is the better way to go about this. It allows you to see a field of 2D data without a 3D plot using colour mapping. The toy example code is here.

```
Y = randn(13558,100);
figure; imagesc( Y );
```

This code generates the image as follows.
[image]
Furthermore, you can use the function `colorbar` to get a bar legend for your data.

```
colorbar;
```

After using the `colorbar` function, it generates the figure below.
[image]